# InputStream returns empty file when downloading a PDF

Tags: android, pdf, inputstream, httpurlconnection, fileoutputstream

So I'm trying to download a PDF file using HttpURLConnection and I think I've done everything right with the input- and outputstreams, yet when I open the downloaded PDF file (using the built in File Manager in Android and/or ADB), or just inspect it by transferring it to OS X, it's completely empty and the size shows 0 bytes.

The site I'm trying to download the PDF from is:

<sub>http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf</sub>

Here's my code

```
    public static void DownloadFile(final String fileURL, final File directory) {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                try {
                    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
                    URL u = new URL(fileURL);
                    c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    //c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                    //c.setDoOutput(true);
                    c.connect();
                    Log.d("debugz", Integer.toString(c.getContentLength()));

                    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len1 = 0;
                    while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    }
                    f.flush();
                    f.getFD().sync();
                    f.close();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();


}


public static String getPDF(String pdfurl) {

    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString();
    File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "schematisktscheman");
    folder.mkdir();
    File file = new File(folder, "schemainfo.pdf");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    DownloadFile(pdfurl, file);

    return null; //added return
}
```

In my main activity:

```
SchedulePdfProcessor.getPDF("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf");
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/schematisktscheman/schemainfo.pdf")));
```

EDIT: I ran the network code on the main thread, which threw an exception. Now creating a new thread for the downloading and it gets the example PDF (http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf) and puts its content in the file all fine.
Thanks to @greenapps!

Comment: "yet when I open the downloaded PDF file, or just inspect it, it's completely empty and the size shows 0 bytes" -- how **exactly** are you doing this? Are you using your desktop OS, with a device that is mounted as a drive or volume? Are you using some on-device file manager? Are you using something else?

Comment: I'm saving the file to my Android device, and then view the file using a File Manager in the OS. The code is running in an app.

Comment: Try changing the loop condition to `(len1 = in.read(buffer)) != -1`

Comment: @cketti I tried that, unfortunately to no avail

Comment: `Oc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf");`. Removel that. You are not sending pdf data to the server.

Comment: `.setDoOutput(true);`. Remove that. You are not doing output.

Comment: Instead of removing code here you could comment those statements. As now my comments make little sense.

Comment: @greenapps I've done both of those things but the PDF is still empty. Thanks for explaining why they don't help too. I've added them back and commented them instead, I figured the edit summaries would explain them but maybe people don't read those.

Comment: GetPdf() is not returning a String. And the url you used is different from the one you talked about.

Comment: @greenapps It's returning a string in my actual code, but that doesn't matter for the problem anyway since the method just needs to download the PDF and output it into the newly created file.

Comment: Void DownloadFile(). Make that boolean. And check return value after use. Place loggings in the catch blocks as now you are not knowing what happens.

Comment: All matters. And you should show good code.

Comment: It is silly to hard code a null return value for getPdf(). getPdf() should return if all went ok. So that you will not call the broadcast receiver when someting went wrong. Please write better code as now you do not know what where happens.

Comment: This is no place to chat.

Comment: `file.createNewFile();`. Remove that statement. The new file output stream will create the file. Moreovelr, even if you have a catch there you call DownloadFile() which is bad practice.

Comment: All the bad code is a result of not having worked with connections before, and desperately adding unnecessary code that I don't need in hope of making it work. Do you think logging c.getContentLength() would help me see if there's any actual content to get?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts, especially once people have taken effort to help and answer. If you want your name removed from the post, flag it for moderator attention and ask for dissociation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the network code on the main thread, which threw an exception. Now creating a new thread for the downloading and it gets the example PDF (http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf) and puts its content in the file all fine.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                try {
                    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
                    URL u = new URL(fileURL);
                    c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    //c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                    //c.setDoOutput(true);
                    c.connect();
                    Log.d("debugz", Integer.toString(c.getContentLength()));

                    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len1 = 0;
                    while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    }
                    f.flush();
                    f.getFD().sync();
                    f.close();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
```

Comment: `ran the network code on the main thread, which threw an exception` . You should have told that right away. And not 'an execption' but a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. And that your app crashed.

Answer (score 1):

First, replace:

```
f.close();
```

with:

```
f.flush();
f.getFD().sync();
f.close();
```

This ensures everything is written to disk before continuing.

Then, you need to use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to get the `MediaStore` to know about the updated file.

Comment: I got rid of the exception using this instead: 

sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/schematisktscheman/schemainfo.pdf")));


The file is still empty though

Comment: @Zino: First, you need to use `scanFile()` (or possibly that broadcast) after downloading, not before. If that does not help, rather than using your desktop OS, use some other tool to check the file (e.g., `adb shell`, DDMS/Android Device Monitor's file manager, an on-device file manager). If it's empty there, then the issue is somewhere in your download code, though that looks fine.

Comment: I've done that now as you can see in my updated question, yet the issue remains.